# Searching for two or more words in string - Python Troubleshooting Program

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, search

I know the code for searching words in a string that match to another string.

```
if any(word in problem for word in keyword_virus):
    #Some code her e.g. pc_virus()
```

But is there any code that would allow me to check if two or more words matched/or even any modifications to this code?

Thank you :)

Comment: With that code you are not searching words in a string. You are searching letters instead! That works if keyword_virus is a list

Comment: keyword_virus = ["virus", "malware", "corrupted", "file", "corrupt", "anti", "alert", "bug", "trojan", "infected"]

Answer (score 1):

```
keyword_virus = 'the brown fox jumps'
print([x for x in ['brown', 'jumps', 'notinstring'] if x in keyword_virus.split()])
#['brown', 'jumps']
```

That will return all matched words in keyword_virus.

Comment: That does not work correctly... if keyword_virus = 'the brownie fox jumps', your function will return 'brown' as well

Comment: Thanks for that. I've amended it to use .split().

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I'd rewrite the for loop to check every word in your checklist and append each match.

```
matches = []
for word in check_list:
  if word in problem_list:
    matches.append(word)
```

You'll end up with a list of words that match, from which you can count the occurrence of each word.

Comment: The question is about strings. Can you make that work for strings instead of lists?

Comment: Simply split the string with `.split()`